# Django - referencing value from template in views.py

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a Pandas dataframe that I am displaying as an HTML table.
I turned the first column of that table into a column of clickable buttons that return a unique value and link to a webpage with information regarding the selected topic.

The col. was turned into a button with the following format:

```
'<button type="submit" name="info" value=' + df['Name:'] + '>More Info</button>'
```

However, in order to display the unique page when the button is clicked I need to be able to reference the button "value"

I have tried referencing the button value from my view in the following ways:

```
if request.POST.get('info', ''):
    value = info.value
    return redirect('detail')

if request.POST.get('info'):
    value = value
    return redirect('detail')
```

However, neither "value" or "info" can be called.

Does anyone know how I can reference the value of the button from my views.py?

edit:

I also tried the following:

```
if request.POST.get('info'):
    value = request.POST.get('value')
    return redirect('detail')
```

No error but it returns the value of value as "None"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just double check if your button is inside of "form" tag, that is the only way to the buttons value got send through. If it doesn't work I think you should be able to get value if you change your "button" to an input tag with type = "submit"

Let me know if it works!

Try this:

in HTML

```
<input type="submit" value="hello" name="info">
```

in .py

```
value=request.POST.get('info')
print(value)
```

it works for me, try and if ot works the problem might be in value you are assigning

Comment: its in a form tag and type is set to submit already, still no luck.

Comment: change your button for an <input type="submit" value="..">

Comment: The value of the button is now returned as "None" even though the button value is set as the df column value in the button

Comment: I just saw your edit and ran the code exactly with my value set as hello and returned "None" again.

Comment: I figured out I was having a separate issue with my forms.py. Thank you.